# Forward single SSH key to given host

Tags: ssh

How do I forward a single arbitrary SSH key to a given host?

Forwarding keys is a security tradeoff, so when you do it, it's ideal to send only what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Start up a ssh-agent just for this connection, add the desired key, then SSH in the subshell.

```
ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add /home/username/.ssh/some_key_id_rsa; ssh -A some_host'
```